# Set In Postman Collection BaseURL

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

Can I create a baseURL in collection level in postman, and in the requests just put the path?

For example I have a Customer Collection (Folder)
Inside there is a `GET/ customers`

instead of writing in the customer collection, in each request the baseURL
I want to declare it the collection, and in the `GET/ customers`, Where I put the url
Just put the path ( `/customers` )

Comment: You should read this doc [Store and reuse values using variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables)

Comment: This is basic functionality and setting baseURL's is in the Postman Learning Centre material.

Comment: @gurkan 
You all not got the question. I have read the docs.
All I asked if there is a way not to write in every request under the same collection the base url.

Comment: @mikee same answer as I answered above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pm.request.url returns a object with fields host, path, and params .

You can replace the whole object with a string or the individual elements.

An example using Postman Echo.

[image]

Then in the pre-request script (which you can set at the request, folder or collection level).

```js
pm.request.url.protocol = "https";
pm.request.url.host = "postman-echo.com";
```

The resulting console log where you can see that the protocol and host have been transposed appropriately.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can get it done.

**Option 1:** Create new Environment and add an environment variable with base url.

**Option 2:** Use Collection's Pre-Request Script to set environment variable for the current selected environment.

**Option 2 Steps**

- Lets say the environment variable name is `base-url`.
  [image]
- And use the environment variable in request textbox as {{base-url}} and it will get the value from the environment variable called `base-url`.
  [image]
- When you hit `Send` button, the Pre-request script runs first and stores the `base-url` variable to environment. After that it will be picked by Postman and it will replace `{{base-url}}` with the value at runtime. It all happens in runtime.
- You can click on EYE icon next to environment dropdown at right top corner and you can see `base-url` would be created after clicking on `Send`.

Personally, I would like to handle it with `Option 1` step because then I can clone the environments for different env such as Dev, Test, UAT etc.

Comment: Thanks,
but it's not really answering my question.
all requests under the same collection (customer collection), I want to put in the {{base-url}} once in the declaration of the collection
and in the requests themself I want to write only the path.

Example:
Collection Customers (Customers is a folder)
Inside there are requests
GET/ 
POST/ 
...

In each request i want just to put the path. without the baseurl.

in the request textbox I just want to write `/v2/customers` and not 
`{{base-url}}/v2/customers`

Answer (score 0):

to set the base URL only once,
Click on the top folder , which is above api
like on FrontAPI if below is structure

FrontAPI 
      ----api
              ----v2
                    ----xfront

Then select tab pre-request scripts
and add the URL there as mentioned by
S.Mishra

This will make baseUrl Available to all the requests under that folder